# Move data in the row out x number of columns based on quantity specified

Tags: excel, vba

I need to shift all data in a row out like this:

```
Qty Shift   Hr 1    Hr 2    Hr 3    Hr 4    Hr 5    Hr 6
1   0   1   1   1           
2.2 3               2.2 2.2 2.2
```

I have a lot of rows and they can be across even a few hundred columns.. hence the help. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details, first give us sample of original data, then give us output which I believe you have described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you need:

```
Sub ShiftData()
  Dim ActiveRow As Range
  Dim InputData As Range

  Set InputData = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))

  For Each ActiveRow In InputData.Rows
    'Paste contents starting column C(3)
    Cells(ActiveRow.Row, 3 + ActiveRow.Offset(0, 1).Value + 0).Value = ActiveRow.Value
    Cells(ActiveRow.Row, 3 + ActiveRow.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1).Value = ActiveRow.Value
    Cells(ActiveRow.Row, 3 + ActiveRow.Offset(0, 1).Value + 2).Value = ActiveRow.Value
  Next
End Sub
```